# pip uninstall broken with -py2.7 in egg path

Tags: python, pip, ubuntu-14.04

It sounds a bit crazy but I'm running into a problem with pip that is happening on some of our ubuntu 14 machines and not others. It is not limited to this package but I'll use 'coverage' as an example

```
$ sudo pip install coverage
```

pip places the install and metadata as follows

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/coverage
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/coverage-3.7.1-py2.7.egg-info/
```

If I try to uninstall, I get an error message

```
$ sudo pip uninstall -y coverage
Can't uninstall 'coverage'. No files were found to uninstall.
```

If I change the metadata path to not contain -py2.7

```
$ sudo mv /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/coverage-3.7.1-py2.7.egg-info/ /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/coverage-3.7.1.egg-info
```

uninstall succeeds with no problem

```
$ sudo pip uninstall -y coverage
   Uninstalling coverage:
Successfully uninstalled coverage
```

This is wreaking havoc with some of our deploy scripts.

Answer (score 1):

The workaround appears to be following the instructions below to install the newest version of pip

https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/installing.html

I'm now at pip 6.0.6 and the current ubuntu provided version is 1.5.4